# Site's gone down…cant figure it out :/

Tags: database, wordpress, load, fatal-error

Im struggling to find out why my site has gone down. Went to login in after a couple of weeks and my site is showing the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'wpdb' not found in /customers/6/a/c/superhuggable.com/httpd.www/wp-includes/load.php:404 Stack trace: #0 /customers/6/a/c/superhuggable.com/httpd.www/wp-settings.php(106): require_wp_db() #1 /customers/6/a/c/superhuggable.com/httpd.www/wp-config.php(98): require_once('/customers/6/a/...') #2 /customers/6/a/c/superhuggable.com/httpd.www/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/customers/6/a/...') #3 /customers/6/a/c/superhuggable.com/httpd.www/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/customers/6/a/...') #4 /customers/6/a/c/superhuggable.com/httpd.www/index.php(17): require('/customers/6/a/...') #5 {main} thrown in /customers/6/a/c/superhuggable.com/httpd.www/wp-includes/load.php on line 404
```

The domain is superhuggable.com. Im not a professional dev, but can normally get my head round most things, was wondering if you guys could help?

Thank you.

Comment: I may suggest to try Google the error message before posting a question here.

Comment: I have pretty much completed google, hence the reason why i am posting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure something is wrong with your WordPress core files. Try re-installing the WordPress. Here's how you can do it without losing your existing site data.

1. Keep the **wp-content** folder and **wp-config.php** file in a safe place. And delete everything else from your wordpress installation directory.
2. Download Wordpress From https://wordpress.org/download/
3. Extract all files. And Replace wp-content folder and wp-config.php file.

If still doesn't work You may try deactivating all of your plugins and themes via the database. (Here's [help](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-deactivate-all-plugins-when-not-able-to-access-wp-admin/))

And also you may try searching guide to fix common wordpress fatal errors.

Happy debugging!